# $P$ is projective . Show that $P$ is a direct summand of a free $R-$ module

Tags: modules, projective-module

$P$ is projective . Show that $P$ is a direct summand of a  free $R-$ module

I am using the definition of a projective module as $P$ is projective if every exact sequence $M\rightarrow P\rightarrow 0$ splits

How to proceed?

Answer (score 6):

Choose generators of $P$ to get a surjection from a free module $F$ onto $P$. This gives you a split (by your definition!) exact sequence $0 \to K \to F \to P \to 0$, showing $F = K \oplus P$.

Comment: What is $K$ here? Why is this a split sequence?

Comment: K should be the kernel of the surjection here, giving us short exact sequence

Answer (score 2):

Since people are rejecting my edits suggesting to write an answer, I do it here:

Let me first reformulate the question to contain all relevant details:

> Assume as definition of projective module the following:
>
> $P$ is projective if every exact sequence $M\rightarrow P\rightarrow
>  0$ splits, that is, for every epimorphishm $f:M \to P$ there exists a
>   right inverse homomorphism $f':P \to M$ such that $ff' = 1_P$
>
> Then, I need to prove the following implication:
>
> If $P$ is projective, show that $P$ is a direct summand of a free
>   $R$-module, that is, there exists a free module $F$ such that $F = P
>  \oplus T$ for some other module $T$.

Then let me add all the details that were neccessary to me based on @MooS' answer:

Choose generators of $P$ to get a surjection from a free module $F$ onto $P$. More precisely, prove that:

> If a module $M$ has a spanning set $X \subseteq M$ then there is an
>   epimorphism $R^{(X)} \to M \to 0$

If you need it, you can find the proof in the book Rings and Categories of Modules, theorem 8.1.

Then what you have is a exact sequence $F \stackrel{f}\to P \to 0$ and taking the kernel $K$ of $f$ we get an exact sequence $0 \to K \stackrel{i}\to F \stackrel{f}\to P \to 0$.

Since $P$ is projective, by your definition, there exists $f'$ such that $ff' = 1_P$ but this is one characterization of being a splitting sequence. Another characterization of splitting sequence is that the center is sum of the non-null extremes, showing that $F = K \oplus P$.